スプレッドシートをPDFでエクスポートするURLのオプションに left_margin を指定するとエラー
以下のURLで、GoogleスプレッドシートをPDFとしてエクスポートすると、
「Google ドキュメント内でエラーが発生しました。このページを再読み込みするか、数分後にこのページをもう一度開いてみてください。」というエラーになります。
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<SPREADSHEET_FILE_ID>/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=<SHEET_ID>&left_margin=0.5&right_margin=0.5
left_margin と right_margin をURLから取り除けばエクスポートできます。
マージンの指定方法が間違っているのでしょうか？

それらのQuery parametersについて、こちらの投稿を見ますと、Margins - you need to put all four in order fir it to works, and they have to be to 2DP. So 0.00 for zero margin.のように書かれています。left_margin,right_marginだけでなく、top_margin,bottom_marginも必要のようです。さらに、値は小数点以下2桁までセットする必要があるとのことです。例えば、適当にtop_margin, bottom_marginを0.50として設定すると、https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<SPREADSHEET_FILE_ID>/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=<SHEET_ID>&left_margin=0.50&right_margin=0.50&top_margin=0.50&bottom_margin=0.50はいかがでしょうか。

実際にテストをしてみますと、left_margin,right_margin,top_margin,bottom_marginのQuery parametersは必要のようですが、値については0.50でなくとも0.5でも問題なさそうでした。一度試してみてください。

@Tanaike できました。ありがとうございます！
